# Find substring in string without includes/indexOf/Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'd like to figure out if a substring is within a string without using the Javascript built in methods of `includes`, `indexOf`, (any similar to those), or regular expressions. Basically just looking to learn an algorithm approach.

This is what I have so far

```
function isSubstring(string, substring){
    substringIndex = 0;

    // loop through string
    for(let i = 0; i< string.length; i++){

       //check the current substring index if it matches 
       if(string[i] === substring[substringIndex]){
           substringIndex++
          //continue searching... Would i then have to call another function recursively?
       }

    }

}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to build the algorithm. Once it finds that first character that matches, I would just go to the next one and if it matches continue to the next index of the string? Would I then need a recursive function that is separate from the looping I am currently doing? I'm trying to get better at algorithmic thinking. Thanks.

Comment: you can take a look at the implementation of `indexOf()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (under the caption polyfill).

Comment: Also, if you're learning and are interested in algorithmic complexity, you might want to take a look into the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: Using recursion would work but would needlessly limit your comparison function to strings that fit into the call stack. You'd also incur a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an optimized example of the algorythm isSubstring. It iterates only through the minimum number of characters required.

For example, if the string is 20 characters long and the substring is only 5 characters long, when we get to the 16th position of the string we can assume that the substring doesn't exist within the string (16 + 5 = 21 > 20)

```js
function isSubstring(str, sub){
  if(sub.length > str.length) return false;
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length - sub.length + 1; i++){
    if(str[i] !== sub[0]) continue;
    let exists = true;
    for(let j = 1; j < sub.length && exists; j++){
        if(str[i+j] === sub[j]) continue;
        exists = false;
    }
    if(exists) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//expected true
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "hello"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "world"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "d"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "o w"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "rl"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", ""));

//expected false
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "hello world 1"));
console.log(isSubstring("hello world", "helloo"));
```

Comment: You don't need the `if(sub.length > str.length) return false;`; the outer `for`-loop will never enter its body unless `0 < str.length - sub.length + 1`. Also, instead of `if(str[i] !== sub[0]) continue;`, the inner `for`-loop can start at `j = 0`. Lastly, you may be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label, which might make this easier to read than your `exists` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Many approaches are possible. Here is one: Create a simpler function which will check if a `first` string is at concrete specified position, let's call it `start`, in a `second` string. It is quite simple: You compare `first[i]` with `second[start+i]` for all `i` in range 0 to length of `first` - 1.

Then the second step will be to repeat this function for all start positions from 0 to length of second string, while checking the boundaries (you cannot read after end of a string).

You can also do some optimizations later, when the first version will work. :-)

Comment: By `start` are you referring to the start index where that first character of the substring is found within the index?

Comment: @nrvaller yes. I try to update the text to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

On each iteration over the `length` of the haystack, use `slice` to extract the characters from that index to (the index plus the length of the needle). If the sliced string matches the needle, return true:

```js
function isSubstring(string, substring) {
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    const sliced = string.slice(i, i + substring.length);
    if (sliced === substring) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(isSubstring('foobar', 'oob'));
console.log(isSubstring('foobar', 'baz'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you expressed interest in a recursive method, here's something to consider. Clicking on the yellow markdown parts reveal the spoilers.

```js
function f(str, sub, i=0, j=0){
  if (j && j == sub.length)
```

> `return true;`

```
  if (i == str.length)
```

> `return false;`

```js
  if (str[i] == sub[j])
    return f(str, sub,
```

> `i+1, j+1);`

```js
  return f(str, sub,
```

> `i+1, 0);`

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function isSubstring(str, sub) {
        return str.split(sub).length > 1
    }
```

No includes, no .indexOf, no RegExp. Just strings.

Answer (score 0):

using only one loop pseudo code :

```js
const containSubstr = (str, substr) => {
  let count = 0;
  let i = 0;
  let startIndex = 0;

  while (i < str.length) {
    if (substr[count] === str[i]) {
      if (count === substr.length - 1) {
        return true;
      }
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 0;
      i = startIndex;
      startIndex++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(containSubstr("ababad", "abad"));
```